# c# webdriver does not know clickAt command, how can I fix this?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I exported Selenium IDE test as C# NUnit webdriver and when I open file with visual studio, I get these errors in lines with clickAt:

> // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [clickAt |....|
>   ]]

How can I fix this problem or maybe I can change clickAt command with another? (note that click command does not get the job done)

Comment: Is it supported?
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2540

Answer (score 2):

There is no default function as far as i know. You need to make one yourself.
It should be something like this:

```
public void ClickAt(IWebElement webElement)
    {
        WaitUntilElementIsClickable(webElement);

        Actions builder = new Actions(this.Driver);
        builder.MoveToElement(webElement).Click().Perform();
    }
```